# glBindBuffer gives error 502 GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: opengl

executing the following code

```
int object::draw(){

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbobuffer);
if(myglError("glBindBuffer in object.draw")){
    //return 0;
}

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, buffer_size);
if(myglError("glDrawArrays in object.draw")){
    return 0;
}

return 1;
}
```

where

```
inline int myglError(const char* location) {
GLenum error = GL_NO_ERROR;
error = glGetError();
if (GL_NO_ERROR != error) {
    printf("GL Error %x encountered in %s.\n", error, location);
    //exit(-1);
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}
```

I get the output
GL Error 502 encountered in glBindBuffer in object.draw.

However glDrawArrays still draws the triangles.

By checking the documentation http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindBuffer.xml
glBindBuffer can return GL_INVALID_ENUM or GL_INVALID_VALUE... but there is no information about glBindBuffer giving GL_INVALID_OPERATION

What is going on here?

Comment: Read the documentation page you linked to a bit more carefully: "While a non-zero buffer object name is bound, GL operations on the target to which it is bound affect the bound buffer object, and queries of the target to which it is bound return state from the bound buffer object. While buffer object name zero is bound, as in the initial state, attempts to modify or query state on the target to which it is bound generates an GL_INVALID_OPERATION error."

Comment: Are you sure that the error is raised by the `glBindBuffer` call? The result of `glGetError` doesn't necessarily reflect the last GL call made. Try checking it just before calling `glBindBuffer`.

Comment: GuyRT, that is the problem, I did not read the glGetError carefully and I overlooked how the glGetError works. It just report all the errors occured since last call and not just the status after a gl function call. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not read the glGetError carefully and I overlooked how the glGetError works. It just reports all the errors occured since last glGetError call and not just the status after a gl function call.

Comment: *"This closes the question."* - No, it doesn't. Neither does adding *"[solved]"* to the title. What does would be you [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/162011) an answer, in this case your own.

Comment: Thanks for explaining me the correct way to close an answer.
I cannot accept my answer today, so I will do it tomorrow!